# SAPUI5: How can display the navigation property of an entity which multiple records in a table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a table with many rows, based on the selected item, it should populate the associated navigation property which also has many records in another table.
I have handled the selectionChange event in my controller to trigger this behavior and I see that it returns the record(s) in my response but it doesn't show the binding in my table. Please help in this regard. This is my code

Controller.js

```
            this.subsystemList.setEnabled(true);
            this.manageDistribution.setEnabled(true);
            
            var sourceSystem = oEvt.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext("pcsdModel").getPath();
            var path = sourceSystem +"/"+"SubSystems";
            
            var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.ColumnListItem();
            this.getView().byId("idSubsystemListTable").bindItems({
                path:path,
                parameters:{
                    expand:"SubSystems"
                },
                length: 1,
                template: oItemTemplate
            });
        },
```

This is my table

```
<Table id="idSubsystemListTable" inset="false">                 
                            <columns>                               
                                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                    <Text text="Source System Level"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                    <Text text="Due Date Reminder"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                    <Text text="Cutoff Date Reminder"/>
                                </Column>
                                <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
                                    <Text text="Actions"/>
                                </Column>
                            </columns>
                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
                                    <cells>
                                        
                                        <Text text="{SourceSystemLevel}"/>
                                        <Text text="{DueDateReminder}"/>
                                        <Text text="{CutoffDateReminder}"/>
                                        <HBox>
                                            <Button icon="sap-icon://edit"/>
                                            <Button icon="sap-icon://delete"/>
                                        </HBox>
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
```

This is the response from the server[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKO11.png)

Comment: Why are you expanding SubSystems twice?

Comment: It seems like you forgot to add the ModelName (the first part of your path) to the binding. Try: `<Text text="{pcsdModel>SourceSystemLevel}"/>`